# How can I remove the trailing space from a capture group for bidirectional text?

Tags: regex, text, editpad

Regex:

```
(((([\u0600-\u06FF])+)\s)+)\↓\s(((([\u0600-\u06FF])+)\s)+)
```

Desired result is that it should only the target text:

```
لَأَرْكُلَنَّكَ رَكْلَةً ↓ لَا تَأْكُلُ بَعْدَهَا بَعْدَهَا أَكْلَةً
```

Actual Result is that the regex captures one extra space at the end as show below:
[image]

As can be see above that at the right side of the Arabic text, there is an trailing space which is causing problem.

I need the regex such that it does not capture the trailing space at the right side of the text. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After rethinking I managed to find perfect solution. Here is the modified regex:
Search for:

```
(([\u0600-\u06FF]+\s+)+)\↓\s(([\u0600-\u06FF]+\s)+)
```

Replace with:

```
$3 ↓ $1
```

> Works Perfectly